# i want to convert sound to numbers

Tags: audio

in audacity you can use sample data import which imports a .txt file with numbers in it and converts the numbers to a sound file. but I want to do the opposite I want to convert sound into numbers. is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your solution is here : http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/sample_data_export.html.

Defition:
`Sample Data Export reads the values of successive samples from the selected audio and prints this data to a plain text, CSV or HTML file. Further information may be added as a "header" at the top of the file.
See also the companion tool Sample Data Import.`

Comment: weird the txt file created just has [-inf] repeated and another one it gives me negative decimal values which cant be read by the sample data import

Comment: I have not worked with audacity before, but from the documentation I figured this would point somewhere in the right direction.